# Set background image of a mutated TableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uitableview, uiview

I am working on a swift project in Xcode right now and one of my view controllers is a UITableViewController. I used swift to alter the size of the table view in the controller so that it does not fill up the entire screen. However, I want to set a background image for the entire view controller which I am unable to do since XCode is not letting me add an image view between the table view controller and the table view. Is there any way to do it using swift? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can help out.

If you're using Apple's UITableViewController - does that mean you altered the tableView's height in the storyboard? I think a better solution is to just use a regular UIViewController, add a tableView with whatever height you want it inside a UIViewController's view.

Often times I would recommend steering away from using Apple's custom things because you lose flexibility. Just make your own custom thing instead!

UIViewController > View > TableView & UIImageView

Make sure your tableview has a clear background!

Comment: The view controller doesn't accept the table view class that I have written because it extends UITableViewController and not UIViewController. Any sudgestions??

Comment: Make it extend UIViewController. Conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Set the `tableView.datasource` and `tableView.delegate` to self. Remove the `override` keywords from the `UITableView` functions.